# How to pass props to components that are taken as props in React functional components with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, react-functional-component

I am trying to make a Calendar component that allows users to optionally pass in a react component as props, so that the users can decide the styling and behavior of the calendar's date items.

```
interface IProps {
    DateItem?: React.ComponentType<{ children: React.ReactNode }>
}

const Calendar = ({
    DateItem
}: IProps) => {

    // ... some code
    const renderCalendarDays = () => {
        const daysInMonth = getDaysInMonth(currentMonth, currentYear);
        const firstDay = getFirstDayOfMonth(currentMonth, currentYear);
        let lastMonth = currentMonth === 0 ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;

        const daysInLastMonth = getDaysInLastMonth(lastMonth);
        const renderedDays = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            renderedDays.push(
                <CalendarItem key={`day-${i}`}>
                    {DateItem ? <DateItem children={i} /> : i}
                </CalendarItem>
            );
        }

        return renderedDays;
    }

    // rest of the code...
}
```

As shown in the for loop, I want to pass the value of i as props to the DateItem component that is passed in. However, when I try to pass a component as props to Calendar, it would throw the following error:

```
// Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{ children: ReactNode; }> | undefined'.ts(2322)
// index.tsx(8, 5): The expected type comes from property 'DateItem' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps

<Calendar DateItem={<SomeComponent />} />
or
<Calendar DateItem={<SomeComponent children={<div>1</div>} />}/>
```

Technically, I can make it work by passing the component in without the fragment shorthand <></>, but I also need to pass other props to the component that I pass in, so this doesn't satisfy my needs either.

```
<Calendar DateItem={SomeComponent}/>

// changing the interface doesnt' help either
interface IProps {
    DateItem?: React.FC<any>
}
```

Comment: `interface IProps<TD extends React.ReactNode> {  DateItem?: React.ComponentType<{ children: TD }>
}; }  const Calendar = <TD extends React.ReactNode>({
    DateItem
}: IProps<TD>) => {`